# How can I compile custom hadoop native codec to libhadoop.so?

Tags: hadoop, compression, native, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins

I have written a native hadoop compression codec. To let it work with hadoop I need to compile native (C code) it to libhadoop.so.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to compile this into libhadoop.so:

- Compile your own .so and distribute to your cluster nodes (into the same directory as the current libhadoop.so
- I assume you've also written your own CompressionCodec (similar to GzipCodec) - add a static block to this code which tries to load the library using `System.loadLibrary("mylibrary");` (for a lib named libmylibrary.so).
- Amend your cluster configuration to include your new compression codec class in the registered list of codecs (amend the `io.compression.codecs` configuration property):
- Restart your task trackers

As a reference, you can follow the implementation and configuration notes for the Google Snappy codec:

- http://code.google.com/p/hadoop-snappy/

Comment: Thanks, that is really a good option and I have decided to go with it.But I came across other isuue,my codec loads liblzma.so file.But when I install this lzma library with apt-get install ..the liblzma.so of size 0 is created and my codec is not able to load it...

Comment: Have you tried removing the re-installing, or install from source?

Comment: Have tried reinstalling but no luck...not aware of install from source..please let me know how to do it?